# iPhone App with Activation Key

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes-store

I am asked by a client to build an iPhone app which works as follow:

- User download the App for free from iTunes
- User enter their email address when they first launch the app
- They will be emailed activation key
- User launch app and then enter this activation key to start using the App.

User do not have to pay for this activation key as the only purpose of this is that only employees of my client company can get the activation code and use it. So when they enter their email address activation key will only be sent if email address is from the same company.

I know I can use enterprise license to distribute app internally but it is not possible due to various reasons.

We do not want to their activation key every time so this will be stored in their settings.

Second questions is that if I want to force them to enter their activation key every month then does this violate apple guidelines.

I want to ask that if I build app as explained above then will it be rejected?

Answer (score 7):

This will be rejected. See guideline 17.2 here:

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: I can confirm that applications which have tried to do this have been rejected, some within the last few months.

Comment: Is there any way around this? The problem is that there are thousands of users who will be using this app and we do not know the complete list to start with. How about if we add a text on the launch screen that they need to contact [email] to get the password. Will this work?

Comment: I also want to know that if they login with username and password and then they do not have to enter it again for next 30 days, will this be acceptable to Apple?

Comment: If the general public can't use the app it won't go into the app store. Period. Try to solve the various problems that hinder you from getting an enterprise license. That's the only way to get your app on an iOS device.

Comment: The main issue is that we do not have the complete list of users who want to access and second issue is that if they leave the company we do not want them to keep on using this app. We might be able to find way around the first issue but do you have any suggestions about blocking access to certain machines? or is there any other solution you can suggest. Any help will be much much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

simply create a session for 30 days, and expire that session in 30 days...
Apple have no issues in expired session plenty of my apps are live with it...
Just give a message you need to login to access the application features or something like that when user get logged out due to session expiration.
Kudos

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if the client creates an enterprise app.  With the enterprise app the app will have to be downloaded from the client's account and is not subject to Apple's restrictions above.