# Iphone app with license key activation

Tags: ios, iphone, license-key

I am working on iOS education app ,to use this app user should enter activation key for that user should contact company custom care then only user can proceed,if i upload this ios app should they accept or reject,what is the best way to build this type of requirement
i have seen some links

[iPhone App with Activation Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508850/iphone-app-with-activation-key])

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5290687?tstart=0

Comment: but i have seen few links ,if i do like this they will reject ,i am sharing those links check it

Comment: App will be rejected if you are using activation key to let user unlock extra content/functionality but if you are asking for activation key on the first page of the app (similar to login functionality to let user use the app) then they will approve your app. What's your case out of these two?

Comment: after login user needs to enter activation key by contacting customer care

Comment: You have 50:50 chance then. But if key is being used to let user enter the app then most likely it'll be accepted once you explain your case clearly to review team. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app would most likely be rejected, since it violates section 3.1.4 of the [*App Store Review Guidelines*](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments):

> **3.1.4 Content Codes:** Apps may not use their own mechanisms to unlock content or functionality, such as license keys, augmented reality markers, QR codes, etc.